# Is the recording in JMeter tool possible?

Tags: sample

guys.

I am currently using the `Apache JMeter tool`. Can you please answer me the following questions:

1. Is it possible to `record and playback`?
2. Can you provide me with sample example about `multithreading`?

Kind regards,
Tomash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomash.

Currently, there is no such functionality available in Apache JMeter. You could simply add multiple requests such as Get/Post and test the application’s performance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I found that there is a record/playback feature. I could simply use an HTTP Proxy Server in Workbench. However, I must set up my browser to use a proxy server. Additionally I must specify the local host and the appropriate port number.

Tomash